# Stacked Text in Bootstrap Navbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to have two sets of text stacked to the left of the navbar. I've tried using nav-stacked and `<br>` but then when resized, and the hamburger menu is displayed it goes all crazy. Is there an effective way to stack text elements in a bootstrap navbar?

Using the picture example, I'd like to set another text object directly under the "Username" text, which is currently being displayed like this:
`<p class="navbar-text">Username</p>`

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone stumbles upon this, I found that putting the `<br>` tag inside of a single `<p>` element works, I did as follows: `<p class="navbar-text">Username<br>Undertext</p>`